# Поиск последнего изменения файла в git

Tags: git

Доброго времени суток.
Вот такой вот вопрос возник: можно ли в git посмотреть в каком из коммитов был изменен определенный файл, и если да - то как?

Answer (score 1):

```
git log <имя файла> - история коммитов по файлу

git blame <имя файла> - когда какая строка файла появилась

man git - справка по git
```